# XML file parsing: how to start

Tags: xml, perl

I need a little help with parsing a xml file. This is my first time doing this kind of task, and I would appreciate some suggestions or help. I have a huge file like this:

```
<Response success="true" start_row="0" num_rows="100" total_rows="100">
<ncbi-genes>
    <ncbi-gene>
        <acronym>Accn1</acronym>
        <alias-tags>BNC1 BNaC1 ACIC2 ASIC2 Mdeg BNaC1a</alias-tags>
        <data-sets>
            <data-set>
                <blue-channel nil="true"/>
                <delegate type="boolean">true</delegate>
                <specimen>
                    <chemotherapy nil="true"/>
                    <donor-id type="integer">9456</donor-id>
                    <donor>
                        <age-id type="integer">1</age-id>
                        <condition-description>TS26</condition-description>
                        <age>
                            <age-group-id type="integer">1</age-group-id>
                            <days type="float">18.5</days>
                        </age>
                    </donor>
                </specimen>
                <differential-expression-rankings type="array">
                    <differential-expression-ranking>
                        <structure>
                            <acronym>PPH</acronym>
                            <name>prepontine hindbrain</name>
                        </structure>
                    </differential-expression-ranking>
                    <differential-expression-ranking>
                        <structure>
                            <acronym>p3</acronym>
                            <name>prosomere 3</name>
                        </structure>
                    </differential-expression-ranking>
                </differential-expression-rankings>
            </data-set>
            <data-set>
              (...same fields as before...)
            </data-set>
        </data-sets>
   </ncbi-gene>
</ncbi-genes>
```

I need to extract:

**1)** {ncbi-genes} -> {ncbi-gene}->{acronym}

**2)** {ncbi-genes} -> {ncbi-gene}->{data-sets}->{data-set}->{specimen}-{donor}->{age}->{days}

**3)** {ncbi-genes} -> {ncbi-gene}->{data-sets}->{data-set}->{{{structure}->{name}

The file contains 100 fields  and the field  can appear more than once inside each .

What I have tried...:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
#use XML::Parser;
use LWP::Simple;  # used to fetch the chatterbox ticker
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file1 = 'file.xml';
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

my $data = $xml->XMLin($file1, ForceArray => 1);
print Dumper($data); ## This prints all data OK

#To print the acronym field
foreach my $genelist (@{$data->{ncbi-genes}}) {
    print $genelist;
    my $curr_gene= $genelist->{ncbi-gene};
    print $curr_gene->{acronym} . "\n"
}
```

This loop is not working.. I think because the "-" inside ncbi-genes. I have change this field to NCBIGENES and now the error is:

```
Not a HASH reference at xml_parser.pl line 19.
HASH(0x29d7ca0)
```

Problem calling the hash... 
As I said, I'm new to this kind of data and it's my first time using xml modules. So, any advice to orient myself would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This script doesn't have 26 lines, which one is the error on?

Comment: Oh, I've removed blank lines to write the post, sorry, the error is on line 19.

Comment: Examine your data dump, with `ForceArray => 1` you'll probably need `$curr_gene->[0]{acronym}`

Comment: Have you read the "Status of this module" section in [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple)?

Comment: Side note: Use quotes, `$genelist->{'ncbi-gene'}`, to avoid having to rename the elements.

Comment: I've not read that @choroba, thanks, so, I guess that is better to use XML::LibXML .. I'm quite lost as you can see :)

Comment: @cucurbit [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) is fairly user friendly -- you might find that nicer to get started with that XML::LibXML.

Comment: "Huge" is meaningless. It can mean anything from 1Mb to 100Gb. There's a big difference, and it might affect how you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example of parsing with [XML::LibXML](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML); XML::LibXML gives you easy access to [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), an XML query language that allows you to select sets of nodes based on their tag names, values, attributes, and/or relationships to other nodes. Using XPath makes it easy to pick out "all *x* nodes under a *y* node," or "all *x* nodes with attribute *z* that have a descendant node with id *w*," or similarly complex queries.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML;

my $tree = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );

## make sure that we have some genes!
die "Could not find any genes!" if ! $tree->exists('//ncbi-gene');

# for every 'ncbi-gene' node:
for my $gene ( $tree->findnodes('//ncbi-gene') ) {
    my %data;
    # is there an acronym as direct child of the node?
    $data{acronym} = $gene->findvalue('acronym') if $gene->exists('acronym');

    # find the donor age in days using the path specified
    # to get the value of each node, run to_literal on it
    $data{donor_age_days} = [ map { $_->to_literal }
        $gene->findnodes('data-sets/data-set/specimen/donor/age/days') ];

    # find all the 'name' nodes under a 'structure' node that is a descendant of $gene
    $data{structures} = [ map { $_->to_literal }
        $gene->findnodes( 'descendant::structure/name', $gene ) ];

    # this will find any 'name' node under a structure node anywhere in the tree
    $data{all_structures} = [ map { $_->to_literal } 
        $gene->findnodes('//structure/name') ];

    # an example of using findvalue on a query that returns an array: only the
    # first value is returned.
    $data{acronyms_str} = [ $gene->findvalue('//structure/acronym') ];

    say Dumper( \%data );
}

__DATA__
<Response success="true" start_row="0" num_rows="100" total_rows="100">
<ncbi-genes>
    <ncbi-gene>
        <acronym>Accn1</acronym>
        <alias-tags>BNC1 BNaC1 ACIC2 ASIC2 Mdeg BNaC1a</alias-tags>
        <data-sets>
            <data-set>
                <blue-channel nil="true"/>
                <delegate type="boolean">true</delegate>
                <specimen>
                    <chemotherapy nil="true"/>
                    <donor-id type="integer">9456</donor-id>
                    <donor>
                        <age-id type="integer">1</age-id>
                        <condition-description>TS26</condition-description>
                        <age>
                            <age-group-id type="integer">1</age-group-id>
                            <days type="float">18.5</days>
                        </age>
                    </donor>
                </specimen>
                <differential-expression-rankings type="array">
                    <differential-expression-ranking>
                        <structure>
                            <acronym>PPH</acronym>
                            <name>prepontine hindbrain</name>
                        </structure>
                    </differential-expression-ranking>
                    <differential-expression-ranking>
                        <structure>
                            <acronym>p3</acronym>
                            <name>prosomere 3</name>
                        </structure>
                    </differential-expression-ranking>
                </differential-expression-rankings>
            </data-set>
            <data-set>
              (...same fields as before...)
            </data-set>
        </data-sets>
   </ncbi-gene>
   <ncbi-favourite-places>
      <structure>
         <name>Eiffel Tower</name>
      </structure>
   </ncbi-favourite-places>
</ncbi-genes>
</Response>
```

Output (note that I've changed your XML a little!):

```
$VAR1 = {
  'acronym' => 'Accn1',
  'donor_age_days' => [
    '18.5'
  ],
  'structures' => [
    'prepontine hindbrain',
    'prosomere 3'
  ],
  'acronyms_str' => [
    'PPHp3'
  ],
  'all_structures' => [
    'prepontine hindbrain',
    'prosomere 3',
    'Eiffel Tower'
  ]
};
```

[zvon.org](http://zvon.org/comp/m/xpath.html) has some good XPath tutorials, which should come in handy when navigating your XML documents--note that libxml, upon which XML::LibXML is based, only implements XPath 1.0, though.

Here's a quick example of gathering data for each `data-set` node:

```
for my $gene ( $tree->findnodes('//ncbi-gene') ) {
    my $data;
    for my $ds ( $gene->findnodes('data-sets/data-set')) {

        # get the age in days -- assumes there is only one age per <data-set>
        my $age = $ds->findvalue('specimen/donor/age/days');

        # get the structures associated with that age
        my @structures = map { $_->to_literal } 
                     $ds->findnodes('descendant::structure/name');
        # you can now save them however you like--e.g.
        push @{$data->{$age}}, @structures;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works really nice, thank you a lot, now, I'll try to understand all lines :)

Comment: Is there any way to group structures related with the age? I mean, I want to know which structures are included for each age.. maybe saving age as a key and structures an array of that key?

Comment: Yes -- you'll probably want to iterate through each data set in turn to ensure that you associate the ages with the structures. I'll add an example to the answer.